# Where does Java store remembered HTTP basic auth passwords and how do you delete them?

Tags: java, http, java-web-start

I have a Java Swing app that launches by web start and accesses data files on a server through a URL. The files are served by Apache2, with HTTP basic Auth. Java pops up a dialog box prompting for a login, and that works fine.

The trouble comes when a user has checked "save this password in your password list". Then the password changes or was incorrect in the first place and you're stuck. It's apparently not smart enough to give you another chance. If your saved login fails you get a 401 error and that's it.

So, where is it storing saved passwords and how do you delete them?

The code involved looks like this:

```
// uri is a String
URL url = new URL(uri);
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

// check HTTP response code
int responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
if (responseCode != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
  throw new IOException("\nHTTP response code: " + responseCode);

// read the file
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader 
               (new InputStreamReader (urlConnection.getInputStream ()));
... etc ...
```

That code works fine, except in this situation where the user has saved a bad password, in which case you get a 401.

My understanding is that Java WebStart puts its hooks into the java.net classes, so that you get things like the password prompt, which you wouldn't get by running the same code from the command line or from your IDE. So, this question is really about that behavior.

Thanks!

Comment: `rm -rf ~` will likely do it on a Linux/Unix/MacOS system. (**Kidding.** Don't try this. It works like burning your house down works for removing a stain from the couch.)

Answer (score 1):

No Code? Now you get a vague answer. Depending on your HttpClient, it's probably stored in the cookies or something. Re-initializing your HttpClient would be a great first debugging step. If that doesn't work, posting a little code here would be very helpful.

Comment: Hi, I added code, but I'm pretty sure the answer is going to be clear a cache or delete a file somewhere, possibly depending on OS. This code has been working for many years, so I have no desire to change the code.

Answer (score 0):

In windows the passwords are saved in below file.

**{user_name}\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\security\auth.dat**

You can delete this file to clear the saved passwords.